# How to create event handler for video buffering?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I need to create an event handler for video buffering, I had a little research which I found `vid.onwaiting = function() {}` This works for to receive new frames of video But I also need to know how much duration of the video have been buffered in seconds.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: buffering is not always contiguous, so you'll need to manually sum up all the ranges.

Comment: @dandavis can you tell me how?